# how to insert two lines into a file after found a word?

Tags: python

I have a file with the following 2 lines at multiple locations.

```
*Element Output, directions=YES
E, FV, MISES, PEEQ, S, TEMP, VOIDR, POR
```

Now I like to add the below 2 lines after the previous two lines at all the locations, could you please give me a hint how to do it? Thanks a lot.

```
*Element Output, POSITION=AVERAGED AT NODES, directions=YES
E, S
```

Thank you so much for your help. I appreicate it.

Comment: Very easy to do this with sed: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: @roudan, have you tried any code. Do you have something we can review? One thing you can do is read the file, search for the two lines with the values, it it matches, then add the two lines then continue reading till end of file. Search every two lines for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple program to add the two lines.

```
line1 = '*Element Output, directions=YES'
line2 = 'E, FV, MISES, PEEQ, S, TEMP, VOIDR, POR'
add1 = '*Element Output, POSITION=AVERAGED AT NODES, directions=YES'
add2 = 'E, S'

#the below two lines will read all the lines in the file
with open("xyz.txt", "r") as f:
    x = f.readlines()

#this line will create a list. each line will be a list item
y  = [i.strip() for i in x]

#open a new file for writing. iterate thru the list
#write the two new lines if you find our two consecutive lines
#else just write the row we read
#do this until the last line on the list

with open('abc.txt','w') as f:
    i = 0
    while i < (len(y)):
        if y[i] == line1 and y[i+1] == line2:
            f.write(y[i] + '\n')
            f.write(y[i+1] + '\n')
            f.write(add1 + '\n')
            f.write(add2 + '\n')
            i+=2
        else:
            f.write(y[i] + '\n')
            i+=1
```

Original file:

```
This is first line and we shouldnt update after this line
*Element Output, directions=YES
E, FV, MISES, PEEQ, S, TEMP, VOIDR, POR
This is line 4. After inserting the two lines, this line should become line 6
This is line 5. Nothing should be added between line 4 and line 5
Same with this line 6. Nothing added between line 5 and line 6
*Element Output, directions=YES
E, FV, MISES, PEEQ, S, TEMP, VOIDR, POR
This is line 9. After processing, there should be two lines above this.
No addition between line 9 and this (line 10)
```

New file with updates:

```
This is first line and we shouldnt update after this line
*Element Output, directions=YES
E, FV, MISES, PEEQ, S, TEMP, VOIDR, POR
*Element Output, POSITION=AVERAGED AT NODES, directions=YES
E, S
This is line 4. After inserting the two lines, this line should become line 6
This is line 5. Nothing should be added between line 4 and line 5
Same with this line 6. Nothing added between line 5 and line 6
*Element Output, directions=YES
E, FV, MISES, PEEQ, S, TEMP, VOIDR, POR
*Element Output, POSITION=AVERAGED AT NODES, directions=YES
E, S
This is line 9. After processing, there should be two lines above this.
No addition between line 9 and this (line 10)
```

Comment: Wow, my goodness Joe. That is really helpful!  You saved me. Wow, I can see the power of python programming. It works!  Thank you so much I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks. If the problem was addressed, you may want to up vote the answer

Comment: Thanks Joe, sorry I forgot it. I just up voted it. I appreciate your help. Have a wonderful weekend!